# Native android 4.0 pdf reader

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am starting to develop app where you basically could buy books and read them on device. 
For this to happen the main problem is to find good free (open source) pdf reader. There are some on the web. 
Ebookdroid, APV pdf viewer and others.

However there performance isn't really impressive. So i know that android don't have any native pdf reader, but i heard somewhere that from Android 4.0 android would support pdf reader. I was searching for this info but really can't find anything.

So android isn't supporting pdf reader in Android 4.0 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Android 2.3 has a built in PDF reader, and Adobe Reader is also Free, between the two I never have a problem reading a document on Android.  I suggest you just focus on creating your market place application for books, and allow the user to select their own pdf reader on their device, unless your going with support beyond pdf of course.  You have a big challenge considering you can read a book your purchased from Amazon any any device you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native PDF support in Android at this time.